# SCSS On Sublime

Tags: sass

I just can't get it work. I have a .scss file with some basic CSS.
Now, I have installed Ruby and I installed SASS like so - gem install sass.
What do I do to get it work on sublime?
I installed "SASS" so sublime acknowledge the .SCSS extension. I also installed SASS builder, and it actually works but in an strange way.

In addition to the compiled css file, it also adds **.map** file and a folder name **.sass-cache**.
Why Is that? How to I get rid of that? I don't need a .map file.
I also get an alert every single time the build is done. ("style.css has been compiled")
And not only that but I also get this comment at the end of my compiled CSS file:

**/*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */**

Please help, I'm lost. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the extra files bothering you? Or do you just want to know why they're created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**--sourcemap=none** will disable the comment as well as the .map file creation. not so hard guys.

also, **--no-cache** will prevent creating the .sass-cache folder and its content.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The .map file is for chrome (and maybe other browsers) to MAP your CSS that is rendered in the browser back to your actual SCSS. This is very very useful when debugging.

The scss-cache is just what it says it is a cache file that Sass uses. You can delete it but it will keep coming back every time you compile.

Once you go to production you can set Sass to not add any comments to your final css output file. You do this through a config.rb file if you are using compass.

Search on YouTube for LevelUp Tuts and Sass Compass install. Scott expanse how to get stared very well.

Comment: Additional info: map files are also used to get the correct line numbers in original versions of TypeScript, CoffeScript, or original versions of minified JavaScript. See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/

Comment: hey thanks for your comment. You haven't said anything about the Alert I keep getting whenever I save/build. It's very, very annoying. about the map file, i don't need it but I don't care about the file, I can just add it to git ignore or something. but the comment line is what very annoying..

Comment: If you arnt using Compass you will have to use command line arguments every time you run Sass watch to remove the comments. Check out the Sass docs to see what arg to use. I would really recommend compass though. Also if you have a page with more then 10lines of CSS the map file will be your best friend. Once you have complicated scss files it will take hours to track down the smallest of bugs.

Comment: Sorry I didnt actually answer your question about the alert. I not sure why you are getting that I only get a line in the terminal telling me the build has finished.

Comment: Guys I solved everything but I seriously wanna get rid of this line - /*# sourceMappingURL=style.css.map */

Comment: If you want to get rid of it then stop using Sass! If you are writing in Sass you want this, if you dont know why you should want it then you shouldnt be using Sass. Stick with plane old CSS

Answer (score 0):

Try using [SassBuilder](https://github.com/bnlucas/SassBuilder) for ST2. And you can config not to include comments, cache,etc with True/False.

```
{
"output_path": "../css",
"options": {
    "cache":         true,
    "debug":         false,
    "line-comments": true,
    "line-numbers":  true,
    "style":         "nested"
    }
}
```

For further info, click [here](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/sublime-text-compiling-sass/).